# connection must be valid and open....Firebird y C#

Tags: c#, firebird

Buen día, me arroja el siguiente error, desconozco el por que, podrían apoyarme :c, soy nuevo con esta base de datos de Firebird, trate de hacerla como lo haría normalmente con SQL, mis demás consultas si funcionan perfectamente pero al momento de ejecutar este método me da ese error. anexo mis líneas de códigos.

```
public static string ObtenerClave(String Articulo)
        {            
            try
            {
                FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand("EXECUTE PROCEDURE precio_individual('" + Articulo + "')", Conexion.Conectar());
                FbDataReader consu = cmd.ExecuteReader();              
                if (consu.Read() == true)
                {
                    Articulo = consu["CLAVE_ARTICULO"].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                   Articulo = String.Empty;
                }      
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            return Articulo;
        }
```

Y esta seria mi clase Conexion:

```
public static class Conexion
    {
        private static readonly string ConnectionString;
        static Conexion()
        {
            var parametros_conexion = new FbConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                DataSource = "192.168.1.100",
                Port = 3050,
                Database = @"D:\Microsip datos\bdempresa.FDB",
                Dialect = 3,
                Role = "USUARIO_MICROSIP",
                UserID = "SYSDBA",
                Password = "masterkey",
                Charset = "UTF8",
                ServerType = FbServerType.Default
            };
            ConnectionString = parametros_conexion.ToString();           
        }
        public static FbConnection Conectar()
        {
            return new FbConnection(Conexion.ConnectionString);
        }
    }
```

Comment: no falta un open en algun lado?

Comment: @gbianchi modifique mi clase conexión para poder agregarle el open y al parecer si funciono, tendría que estar cerrando la conexión como si fuera en SQL?

Comment: ni idea.. no conozco como funcionan esas conexiones..

Comment: *tendría que estar cerrando la conexión. . .?*. Por supuesto. Qué te llevó a pensar que las conexiones no se cierran?